# Upload image to rich text field and choose destination

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload, rich-text, image-upload

SharePoint 2013, Team-Site-Template

I got a custom list with a rich text field. This offers the option to upload images to. There also is a doc. lib. with 3 folders on this site. The upload form displays the dialog elements for choosing file from computer and an element called "destination". But this element is just a dropdown select to choose the doc. lib. for the upload. There is no option to choose the folder. In my case I need the user to choose the proper folder as each Item is only visible to spec. user groups and therefor the attached image or doc. needs to be placed in the folder of the doc. lib that is also visible to this usergroup.

In one sentence:

How can I make it possible that users can choose the destination folder when uploading a file to a rich text field in a custom list item?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this guide](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/25/sharepoint-2013-now-you-can-add-documentsvideo-audio-in-rich-text-fields/) you should be able to choose any **library** on your **site** to upload the picture.

Does the dropdown-menu not give you any choices? Do you have any libraries on your site?

---

**To make pictures automaticly get assigned to a folder without any custom sharepoint-feature**

The simplest idea i got is to use prefix on images combined with a Sharepoint-workflow to assign it's folder.

So the solution would mean that you upload a image as required and then as name ad a prefix like this:

Let's say that the different folders are "**/cars/**" "**/boats/**" and "**/airplanes/**".

I wanna upload an image of a Boeing 777, which is an airplane, i would upload the picture with the name "/airplanes/boeing777.jpg".

So the picture will appear in your library which will be something like a central-station for your pictures of vehicles.

In this picture-library you will have a workflow which starts on every item that's created or changed and check if the image-name contains the different names of your folders and then change the destination-folder to match the pictures name.

The workflow can be created in Sharepoint-designer that's available for download from microsoft for free.

[More info about creating workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671(v=office.15).aspx)

There might bea better sollution for this using a feature or simular.

Comment: Hi, yes shure I am able to choose the destination library but not the proper folder in this lib.. I got 3 folders with unique permissions and attachments must be put in one of these folders. In my opinion the form goes just half the way... when I can upload something I need to be able to choose the exact destination an not only the root of a library. Of course I could just create 3 libraries with proper permissions that will apear in the upload form. But I am wondering why the folder-choose-input form field is just missing...

Comment: I can't see support for this OOTB, i do however have a sollution that you could use without any Sharepoint-Feature :) Ill edit my answer.

Comment: I also thought about using a workflow. But I guess nearly all users would miss to add the proper foldername to the image filename (or they even don´t know the foldernames at all). So this might not work because of usability issues. So I think I stick with just using 3 libraries instead of 1 lib. with 3 folders to use the libs. like folders. I read about a feature called "drop off library" that might be a good solution but I haven´t figured out yet.

Comment: You could ofcourse have 3 libraries and 3 workflows which migrates the documents from each library into a main-library with different folders. That would probably get you the right result, even tho it's a silly solution :)